# Can docker containers share a directory amongst them

Tags: docker

Is it possible to share a directory between docker instances to allow the different docker instances / containers running on the same server directly share access to some data?

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the same host directory to both containers `docker run -v /host/shared:/mnt/shared ...` or use `docker run --volumes-from=some_container` to mount a volume from another container.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is what "Docker volumes" are.  See [Managing Data in Containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/):

> ### Mount a Host Directory as a Data Volume
>
> [...] you can also mount a directory from your own host into a container.
>
> `$ sudo docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py`
>
> This will mount the local directory, /src/webapp, into the container as the /opt/webapp directory.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Creating and mounting a Data Volume Container
>
> If you have some persistent data that you want to share between containers, or want to use from non-persistent containers, it's best to create a named Data Volume Container, and then to mount the data from it.